# Check if a preference exist from Firefox extension

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

How to check if preference exist?

I need to create a new preference in the Firefox configuration, but I can't know whether it exists already.

```
var firstRun = prefs.getBoolPref('extensions.addon.firstRun');
```

> Error: NS_ERROR_UNEXPECTED: Component returned failure code: 0x8000ffff (NS_ERROR_UNEXPECTED) [nsIPrefBranch.getBoolPref]

Comment: [Does this help you](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Code_snippets/Preferences#check_For_Existence)? (< 30s with non-Google searchengine searching for "preference mdn firefox")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already stated by @try-catch-finally, [MDN already has some code snippets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Code_snippets/Preferences#check_For_Existence).

I personally would however use @try-catch-finally's user name :p, e.g.

```
var somePref = false;
try {
  firstRun = prefs.getBoolPref('extensions.addon.somePref');
}
catch (ex) {
  prefs.setBoolPref('extensions.addon.somePref', somePref = true);
}
```

Well, **even better** would be if you [added some default preferences](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Default_Preferences) ([more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Code_snippets/Preferences#Default_preferences)) to your extension! Especially "first run" preferences are almost predestinated for this.

In `defaults/preferences/somefilename.js` add e.g.

```
pref("extensions.addon.firstRun", true);
```

Make sure to read through the [Preferences](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Code_snippets/Preferences) article. In particular preference observers often are quite useful. ;)